Multilevel model where skew of random effect depends on an independent variable
I am trying to construct a model where the skew of the distribution of a random effect changes with an independent variable. I'd eventually like to fit this using brms in R. Here's a concrete example analogous to my data:
Say I run a grocery store, and I want to understand how the amount of food items sold changes depending on the weather. So I collect data on sales of every item in the store and the daily temperature high. I also suspect that the spiciness level of the food item influences response to temperature, so I collect a spiciness score for each type of food as a continuous variable.
The standard way to proceed is to make a multilevel model with an interaction term between temperature and spiciness and varying slopes for food items. So for P (amount purchased of a food), T Temperature and S spiciness
$$
log(P_i) \sim Normal(\mu_i, \sigma_i)
\\\mu_i = \alpha_{FOOD[i]} + \beta_{FOOD[i]}T + (\beta_S + \beta_{ST}T)S
\\ \begin{vmatrix}
\alpha_{FOOD[i]}\\ 
\beta_{FOOD[i]}\\
\end{vmatrix} \sim MVNormal(\begin{vmatrix}
\alpha\\ 
\beta\\
\end{vmatrix}, \Sigma)
$$
with various specified priors for the different parameters and the variance-covariance matrix. This should detect whether spiciness changes the effect of temperature on the sale of a food item, but allows slopes to vary among food items.
However, where I'm running into trouble is that I suspect a scenario where sales for most food items are not highly affected by temperature, but the foods that are most affected by temperature tend to be spicier on average, becoming less popular as temperature increases. At the same time, many equally spicy items show no change with response to temperature (perhaps because they were not popular to begin with). I'm concerned because if this is the case, the model specified above may struggle to capture the effect of spiciness because the mean value may not change much. If this is the case, the random slopes may follow distributions something like this, where the mean value of $\beta_{FOOD[i]}$ is the same but the skew is shifted based on spiciness:

Therefore I'm considering a model something like this where I fit spiciness as a predictor of skew for the random slope
$\beta_{FOOD[i]}$
$$
log(P_i) \sim Normal(\mu_i, \sigma_i)
\\\mu_i = \alpha_{FOOD[i]} + \beta_{FOOD[i]}T + \beta_SS
\\ \begin{vmatrix}
\alpha_{FOOD[i]}\\ 
\beta_{FOOD[i]}\\
\end{vmatrix} \sim MVSkewNormal(\begin{vmatrix}
\alpha\\ 
\beta\\
\end{vmatrix}, \Sigma, D)
\\D = \alpha_D + \beta_{S, Shape}S
$$
The, I think I would need to specify priors for $\beta_{S, Shape}$ and $\alpha_D$, as well as the other parameters. Here, I think we might be able to say, for instance that spicy foods increase the likelihood of a higher slope (without really changing the mean $\beta_{FOOD[i]}$
So I guess my questions are:

Is it valid to set up a model this way/is it potentially more effective than just including a standard interaction term? Or is there an alternative way that is more likely to capture the effects that I'm interested in?

Can I implement something like this in brms and what would the syntax look like?



This is an interesting question (+1). Have you seen that you can fit a random effect as t-distributed in brms? See https://discourse.mc-stan.org/t/non-normal-random-effects-in-glmm/7373/11
